# When trying to access a site deployed on Netlify "Page Not Found"

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I'm a complete beginner to web development and am trying to deploy my first site via Netlify. Despite my site working fine when being displayed from my local machine, I'm given the following error when navigating to my site's URL:

Comment: It needs some more information with some screenshots.

Comment: Some more details in your Question would be useful, eg: How have you deployed the site? What stack are you using? What are the build configurations in the Netlify dashboard?